# MVC 5 or MVC 6 for a MVC beginner

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

I am a .net developer with 10+ years of experience  however never got an opportunity to work with MVC or EF. As I am looking for other opportunities , i started looking in MVC 5 and other new technologies/frameworks. I got my fundamentals however with recent release of MVC 6 , am confused now to learn what. It seems MVC 6 is a lot different fundamentally as System.web,httpcontext,global.asax and lot other places are changed in MVC 6. I am planning to get a book or Pluralsight subscription and study MVC in more detail with some lab and hands on practice. Do you guys think i should do it with MVC 5 and when MVC 6 is released it will be on top of it or start with MVC 6 directly to avoid any confusion . Your help is appreciated.

Any website/books suggestion ?

Edit- 
It seems MVC 5 is way to go . Any other technology along with it which goes together?

Comment: actually mvc6 is not released yet... the tutorials which you are seeing on web is vnext ie what microsoft is planning to give in mvc6....in my opinion learn mvc5 first....

Comment: apress pro mvc5 is best book to learn mvc5

Comment: MVC6 is still in development, and many things are still in flux.  In fact, even published articles are already wrong a few weeks after publishing because of changes.  I'd stick with MVC5, as there won't be any stable tutorials or books for quite some time for MVC6.  What's more, it's unlikely you'll find many jobs that are willing to jump on bleeding edge anyways.  In fact, it might be wise to try to do some development in earlier versions as well (MVC4) as there are many jobs still working with this version.

Comment: I suggest start with MVC5. By the time you know the basic stuff. MVC6 will be out and you can learn that too

Comment: I stay with MVC 5, because MVC5 is still modern, and enough for a great product.

It is RAD developement compare to MVC6.
MVC6 project is bigger and annoyed. 
Microsoft remove many things like Bundle and Minify CSS/JS, scaffolding GUI (use command line instead). 

Also Microsoft already have Nuget, but MS add Npm, Bower repo in ASP.NET 5.0, it is messy and not necessary. 

Stay with MVC 5.0 , you will learn the spirit of ASP.NET MVC. 
IMO,MVC 6.0 is just a experimental version. 

Modern web development is going to light-weight as possible, but not make it fat and complex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're just starting with ASP.NET MVC, MVC 5.0 will do as most of what you'll learn can be transferred to version 6 when it's released.

I would also recommend learning a front-end MVW framework such as AngularJS with ASP.NET WebAPI.

Most of the knowledge in learning the MVC pattern is transferable to AngularJS and you can use WebAPI as a back-end to build a robust API for your apps (which you can re-use later to take your applications to other platforms such as iOS or Android)

The asp.net website is a great place to start:

http://www.asp.net/web-api

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started